# I keep getting this error when trying to use pip install. I am new to coding and quite confused

Tags: python, pip

$ pip install windows-curses

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.ex
e"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install windows-curses': The system cannot fi
nd the file specified.

Comment: You likely need to put the full path to pip.exe as part of your install command. Your computer is looking for a pip.exe where one doesn't exist. You might need to install pip. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you didn't select to add Python to path in the installer, or you never installed pip. Try adding Python to path by reading this article: [How to add Python to PATH variable in Windows](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows). You could also try installing pip if you haven't already by running this command in command prompt: `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`. If the command doesn't work, try running command prompt in administrator. If all else fails, try reinstalling the newest version of Python. Hope this helped!